# Does ConvertFrom-Json respect -ErrorAction

Tags: json, powershell, error-handling

I'm writing a script that needs to parse JSON and I'm getting errors on some files. The errors are because of invalid JSON, which is fine, but I want to be able to detect this and handle it in the script. It doesn't seem like `ConvertFrom-Json` supports `-ErrorAction`, tho. Is that true? I don't see anything about that online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ErrorAction is a Common Parameter which was added in PowerShell 2

From the [ConvertFrom-JSON MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertFrom-Json)

> CommonParameters
>
> This cmdlet supports the common parameters: -Debug, -ErrorAction,
>   -ErrorVariable, -InformationAction, -InformationVariable, -OutVariable, -OutBuffer, -PipelineVariable, -Verbose, -WarningAction, and -WarningVariable. For more information, see about_CommonParameters
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216).

Edit: This is a [bug logged on the PowerShell GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2860) for PowerShell 5 and 6

Comment: Saw that... but it's not working :-/ `$text | ConvertFrom-Json -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` results in an unhandled error. I worked around it by adding a `try`/`catch` block for now.

Comment: Looks like this is a [bug logged on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2860)

Comment: Just for completeness' sake : the github bug was closed *The proposed fix for this was not accepted and resolved as by-design*

Comment: Still exhibits in Powershell 7 as well.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs in version 5,6 and 7. You could use a try-catch block. Or you could try the next approach:

```
    # Get Data from JSON File
    $data = Get-Content ".\data.json" | ConvertFrom-Json;

    # Check it is valid
    if(!$data) { 
      throw [System.ArgumentException]"Invalid Data File." 
    }
```